# How do i make the (.date) text background color a gradient (fade out)?

Tags: css, text, background, fade

I currently have a text-background color behind my "date" spanning the width of a text box. I would like to add in this to it so it fades out on the right. But when I add this in , it just make the text a gradient, and the background disappears.

```css
background-color:-webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 100%, 0 0, from(white), to(#55565a), color-stop(80%, #55565a));
```

---

```css
.date { 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 9px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #adadad;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:-41px;
    margin-right:-41px;
    padding-left:30px;
    display : block;
}
```

UPDATE:

light blue stripe:

```css
hr {
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;    
color: #B7C3E6;
background-color: white;
height: 25px;
margin: 0px auto;
opacity: 0.2;
border: none;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 100%, 0 0, from(white), to(#B7C3E6), color-stop(80%, #B7C3E6));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKfU6/)**

```css
.date { 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 9px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #adadad;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:-41px;
    margin-right:-41px;
    padding-left:30px;
    display : block;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(173,173,173,1) 0%, rgba(173,173,173,0.18) 82%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(173,173,173,1)), color-stop(82%,rgba(173,173,173,0.18)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(173,173,173,1) 0%,rgba(173,173,173,0.18) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(173,173,173,1) 0%,rgba(173,173,173,0.18) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(173,173,173,1) 0%,rgba(173,173,173,0.18) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(173,173,173,1) 0%,rgba(173,173,173,0.18) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#adadad', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

Use [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate gradients.

Comment: Wow, thats a lot of css. What is the URL for? So to change the start color, this makes it difficult for me. Im a noob, sorry.

Comment: So this light blue stripe I have on my site, wont transfer to other browsers?

Comment: @Jeff Dowell Like I mentioned, the URL is to generate cross browser CSS gradients. Check it out, its very simple. You can customize the colors to your liking :-)

Comment: got it, I see your "Use CSS Gradient Generator to generate gradients." note'

Comment: Here is an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKfU6/1/)** with the blue color you mentioned, and if I answered your question please hit the green check mark :-).